# Pasting on input field via python

Tags: python, python-2.7, xdotool

I am having difficulty finding a proper solution to paste my input into a input field. I am using the **library Xdo.**

**What am i doing ?**

The Python file is running in the backend.

The program fetches data from a **Smart card**.

Data returned are numerical / English and Thai.

Then in browser, when I click to a input button, then the values are to be pasted in to the input button.

**What is the issue?**

The **numerical data** (ID card/ Birthday ) is printed correctly in the browser.

The **thai texts** are giving trouble. They are not inserted or partially inserted sometimes.

***This used to work in **windows** machine but I was using a different library (SendKeys for windows program). But using Xdo on **linux** is giving me trouble.***

Following is my sample code

```
 from xdo import Xdo
 xdo = Xdo()
 res = convert_data(resultlist)
 title_th = res['title_th']
 fname_th = res['fname_th']
 lname_th = res['lname_th']
 birthday = res['birthday']
 address = res['address']

 win_id = xdo.get_focused_window()
 xdo.enter_text_window(win_id, res['id'])
 xdo.send_keysequence_window(win_id,'Tab')
 xdo.enter_text_window(win_id,str(title_th.decode('tis-620')))
 xdo.send_keysequence_window(win_id,'Tab')
 xdo.enter_text_window(win_id,str(fname_th.decode('tis-620')))
 xdo.send_keysequence_window(win_id,'Tab')
 xdo.enter_text_window(win_id,str(lname_th.decode('tis-620')))
 xdo.send_keysequence_window(win_id,'Tab')
 xdo.enter_text_window(win_id,str(birthday.decode('tis-620')))
 xdo.send_keysequence_window(win_id,'Tab')
 xdo.enter_text_window(win_id,str(address.decode('tis-620')))
 xdo.send_keysequence_window(win_id,'Tab')
```

The Following is a sample image.

As you can see, some Thai texts are partially entered and others are skipped.

[image]

Looking for any suggestions, or any alternatives to my current solution is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the above issue without depending on Python libxdo tools.

I have managed to solve by using command line xdotool and xsel .

Check this link for detailed information [SOLVED](https://askubuntu.com/a/875947/517301)